# Measure object to add object of ints together

Tags: powershell

I have imported a CSV table, with names and ages.
I have converted the ages to integers, but cannot work out why measure object is not giving me a sum.

```
$import = Import-Csv C:\path\test.csv
$csv = $import | Select @{Name="Age"; Expression={[int32]$_.Age}}
$csv | measure-object
```

OUTPUT:

```
Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

Maybe I'm just being dumb but can't work out why it can work out how many are there but can't just give me a sum...

Many thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with made-up data. Import the CSV and tell `Measure-Object` to sum the age column like so,

```
id,name,age
1,foo,10
2,bar,15
3,zof,25

$c = Import-Csv C:\Temp\ages.csv
$c |Measure-Object -Property age -Sum

Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      : 50
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : age

# Shorthand for just the sum
($c |Measure-Object -Property age -Sum).sum
50
```